# Assign a different style to a single menu item in the Helix3 framework (Joomla 3)

Tags: css, joomla, helix

There is a site on Joomla3 with Helix3 framework. I need to assign a different style to specific menu item (another color).
Through, for example, item-565 does not work.
All parent menu items have the same color.
Help me please ))

Answer (score 0):

This is joomla docs for making it: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Switching_templates#Assigning_more_than_one_template_for_the_Front-end